# RegularExpression validating format (ABC_123)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

**UPDATED:**

did not work... after i enter the correct format i still see the error poping...

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtId"
ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{3}"
ErrorMessage="Invalid Id" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**UPDATED END**

**EDIT:**

ALLOWED:

ABC_123

NOT ALLOWED

ABC123 or ABC OR 123123 OR ABC-123

**END EDIT**

how to validate `("ABC_123")` in regular expression?

for an example:

```
// Instance method:
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z'.]{1,40}$");
Response.Write(reg.IsMatch(txtName.Text));

// Static method:
if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtName.Text, 
                   @"^[a-zA-Z'.]{1,40}$"))
{
  // Name does not match schema
}
```

Comment: What is allowed and what is not allowed to be matched? Are parenthesis and quotes part of the match? Give few more examples (both positive and negative).

Comment: Please indicate which of the following are allowed: `SED_456` `AB_123` `BC_123` `FGHIJKL_875643` `ABC_123` `ABC.123` `HELLO_000` `Hello_999` - in other words, is it supposed to be three capital letters, underscore, then three numbers, or is it supposed to be any number of letters (capital or lowercase), then an underscore, then any number of digits, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex match = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{3}$");
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Regex for finding ABC_123 could be like this `[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{3}`

Comment: i did a quick test on the expression you provide and it did not work, you can check out this here http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: Dont know what kind of error you get. I just tested in my code and here http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx. It works good for me!

Comment: i did not mean error in the regexpression what i meant by: after i enter the right code that is `abc_123` the regexpression still thinks i have a wrong format.